# Python opens a second window. Why?

Tags: tkinter, filedialog

I have a piece of code that gives me a bit of trouble. When I run it, I expect it to run the filedialog.askopenfilename only. However it also opens a small Tk window on the top-left corner of the screen. I am not sure why since there is nothing in my code (that I know of) calling for such Tk window.

Could you explain this for me?

```
from getpass import getuser
from sys import platform
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

userID = getuser()

try:
    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        userpath = os.path.join("/", "home", userID, "Checklist_PDFs")
        print(userpath)
        filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=userpath, title="Select a file")

    elif platform == "darwin":
        userpath = os.path.join("/", "home", userID, "Checklist_PDFs")
        print(userpath)

    elif platform == "win32":
        userpath = os.path.join("c:", "\\", "Users", userID, "My Documents", "Checklist_PDFs")
        print(userpath)
except:
    print("My note: cannot execute")
```

Comment: I got this, thank you for telling me how to prevent the second window to open. However, I am trying to understand what part of my code prompted the Tk window to open. Is it the filedialog function that creates a Tk window?

Comment: I just posted an answer, added some explanation there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to do sth like this (create a `Tk` instance and immediately `.withdraw()` it, that way it won't pop up, the reason it happens is that `filedialog.askopenfilename()`(or any other such window) requires a master, if there is none, it will create one. The reason that is the case is because there should be only one instance of `Tk`, so all these additional windows are most likely based on `Toplevel()` which requires a master, but they can be created as much as needed since they don't require their own `.mainloop()` or sth):

```py
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

So in your code it would look like this:

```py
from getpass import getuser
from sys import platform
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk
import os


root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

userID = getuser()

try:
    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        userpath = os.path.join("/", "home", userID, "Checklist_PDFs")
        print(userpath)
        filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=userpath, title="Select a file")

    elif platform == "darwin":
        userpath = os.path.join("/", "home", userID, "Checklist_PDFs")
        print(userpath)

    elif platform == "win32":
        userpath = os.path.join("c:", "\\", "Users", userID, "My Documents", "Checklist_PDFs")
        print(userpath)
except:
    print("My note: cannot execute")
```

Also I suggest that you handle the exceptions like this (if you don't know what to expect):

```py
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will print out the exception, so you know what exception exactly was raised (and will also comply with PEP 8 or sth, or at least my IDE itself doesn't like too broad exception clauses)

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you for the tip on how to handle the exception.